# Doubts about Security in Login for Web with Facebook Oauth JavaScript SDK that send ACCESS TOKEN to server

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, access-token

I have doubts about security of my process of authentication oauth with facebook..

I use login for web with javascript sdk with fb button:

I get an Access Token successfully and pass it to server(calling check_facebook_session.php) to make API call to Facebook Provider..
In the following code there is also the log in console of access token.

Everything works!!! on the server I use the php sdk to call the API REST with APPID, APPSECRET and ACCESS_TOKEN:

**
Now my question, have I a security problem? 
Is a bad idea to pass the token to the server?
The token that is visible on the client can be used WITHOUT APP SECRET to get information    about the user logged?
**

Note: Google+ Sign-In for server-side apps  Implementing the one-time-code flow with step:

```
- Include the Google+ script on your page.
- Add the sign-in button to your page.
- Sign in the user.
- Send the authorization code to the server.

as explained in: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow
```

Unlike facebook google in the js client return a CODE, not an ACCES TOKEN and the server receive and use it to request ACCESS TOKEN.

Thanks..

```
Following is the javascript code for facebook:

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : FACEBOOK_APP_ID, // App ID
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : false, // enable/disable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response)
  {
    if (response.status === 'connected')
    {
      var accessToken = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
      console.log(accessToken);

      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: check_facebook_session.php,
          contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
          processData: false,
          data: 'token=' + accessToken,
          success: function(result)
          {
            if(result == 'SUCCESS'){window.location.href = fb_callback_url}
          },
          error: function(xhr)
          {
              alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' ' + xhr.responseText);
          }
        });
    }
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized')
    {
      FB.login();
    }
    else
    {
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
.......
  }(document));
```

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing and came to the conclusions that I hope can be useful.

In Facebook SDK for JavaScript it automatically handles access token storage and tracking of login status, so apps using it do not need to create their own mechanisms for doing so, and can proceed to making API calls.

The system seems safe because I believe that the callback url of the call is the site that host the page and configured between those of the facebook application, so I can change the application id in the javascript code but the sdk response with error message and get the user's token pretending to be another application. This was already obvious to those who know the flow :-)

Passes the token to the server is definitely a bad idea because it can be snorted and used by simply calling https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=... to get user information, In the different flow of google the token is not passed but is passed the code necessary to obtain it.

The best solution to use advantage of client and server is it:

Used in conjunction with the Facebook SDK for JavaScript,
the PHP SDK can share user sessions seamlessly across the client and server.
If people are logged in with Facebook and have authorized your app,
the JavaScript SDK can pick up the user session and persist this in a cookie,
which the PHP SDK reads without any intervention on the developer's part.
To enable this functionality, ensure that when you embed and initialize the JS SDK,
you set both the status and the cookie parameters of the object passed to FB.init() to true.

Regards..

Comment: I'm not sure I get your answer thoroughly, APPID(or API KEY as in https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication) can be used to get non-user-specific info. But APPID is visible on the javascript site client. So is it safe or not?

Answer (score 0):

i think it is secure because the user's data is only returned with **connected** status after user authentication with facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Answer (score 0):

I have followed Facebook example on getting access token by using `$fb->getJavaScriptHelper();`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_access_token_from_javascript

```php
$helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
echo $accessToken->getValue();
```

P.S. Add `try{} catch() {}` blocks, as in Facebook example for error handling.